# Accessing dictionary value from list of dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, robotframework

I am using a keyword that returns a list of dictionaries like the one below. If I loop through the dictionaries I can get the values. For example,

```
${vPools} =      list all vpools
: FOR    ${Item}    IN    @{vPools}
\    ${vPoolID} =     ${Item["VPoolID"]}
```

Is there a way to access a value directly without looping? Something like

```
${vPoolID} =   @{vPools[0]}["VPoolID"]
```

for the first list item? I keep trying different things but can't seem to find the right recipe.

```
17:23:30.815    INFO    [
    {
        "GroupType": 3, 
        "GroupTypeEnum": 3, 
        "Name": "GS - Flash - Protection: 1 - QoS: Gold", 
        "OptimizationSetting": 0, 
        "OptimizationSettingEnum": 0, 
        "PhysicalPoolID": "7efaf334-b723-4be6-af56-3a626562b553", 
        "ProtectionSetting": 1, 
        "QoSClassPriorityID": 1, 
        "Secured": false, 
        "TotalCapacity": 0, 
        "UsedCapacity": 0, 
        "VPoolID": "be7d518e-9851-4ad5-bd59-c7987fc3dd9b"
    }, 
    {
        "GroupType": 3, 
        "GroupTypeEnum": 3, 
        "Name": "GS - Flash - Protection: 1 - QoS: Silver", 
        "OptimizationSetting": 0, 
        "OptimizationSettingEnum": 0, 
        "PhysicalPoolID": "7efaf334-b723-4be6-af56-3a626562b553", 
        "ProtectionSetting": 1, 
        "QoSClassPriorityID": 2, 
        "Secured": false, 
        "TotalCapacity": 0, 
        "UsedCapacity": 0, 
        "VPoolID": "1a82e650-589e-4077-878b-48eea7211278"
    }, 
    {
        "GroupType": 3, 
        "GroupTypeEnum": 3, 
        "Name": "GS - Flash - Protection: 1 - QoS: Bronze", 
        "OptimizationSetting": 0, 
        "OptimizationSettingEnum": 0, 
        "PhysicalPoolID": "7efaf334-b723-4be6-af56-3a626562b553", 
        "ProtectionSetting": 1, 
        "QoSClassPriorityID": 3, 
        "Secured": false, 
        "TotalCapacity": 0, 
        "UsedCapacity": 0, 
        "VPoolID": "5a082095-cbb5-460a-a0fc-0a8dc90d007d"
    }
]()
```

Comment: Both yours and the 2nd answer worked like a charm :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collections library has keyword Get From Dictionary. I think it is what you are looking for:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Dictionary
    ${dict1}=      Create Dictionary     GroupType=3    VPoolID=be7d518e-9851-4ad5-bd59-c7987fc3dd9b
    ${dict2}=      Create Dictionary     GroupType=3    VPoolID=1a82e650-589e-4077-878b-48eea7211278
    ${vPools}=     Create List           ${dict1}       ${dict2}
    ${vPoolID}=    Get From Dictionary   @{vPools}[0]   VPoolID
```

Comment: Only reason I also answered was that if you do not want to assign the value to a variable, but simply want to use it as in Should Be Equal, using Get From Dictionary requires an extra line and variable.

Comment: This and the first comment both worked! Many thanks :-) My attempts tended to look like the first answer, yours was completely different. Both were educational. This is my first time using Robot Framework.

Comment: I also learned a new way to access list of dictionaries from ombre42's answer

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can access nested collections if you use the [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax). This comes in quite handy when working with DatabaseLibrary and SudsLibrary. Make sure to put the keys and indices inside the curly braces and put your keys in quotations.

```
List of Dictionaries
    ${a}    Create Dictionary    a=1    b=2
    ${b}    Create Dictionary    x=5    y=7
    ${stuff}    Create List    ${a}    ${b}
    ${item}    Set Variable    ${stuff[0]['b']}
    Should Be Equal    ${stuff[1]['x']}    5
```

So try:

```
${vPoolID}    Set Variable    ${vPools[0]["VPoolID"]}
```

Since you are referencing a single item, do not use @, but use $ instead.

Comment: Worked like a champ!

Answer (score 0):

Your closing curly brace needs to be outside your second set of square brackets.

```
${vPoolID} =   ${vPools[0]["VPoolID"]}
```